# Local Histogram Separation Energy Implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working in level set method, specially Lankton method [paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjjlpx0ecyhbo0b/lankton.pdf). I try to implement Histogram Separation (HS) Energy problem (Part III.C). It based on Bhattacharyya to control the evolution of contour. To understand it, the first we consider global method in which given an input image and a contour. The contour divides the image into inside and outside region. The Bhattacharyya distance is calculated by

```
B=sqrt (P_in.*P_out)
```

where P_in and P_pout are pdf of inside and outside regions.
To applied Bhattacharyya  for global level set you can see source code at [here](http://jgmalcolm.com/pubs/research.html#downloads-for-matlab). Now we return the Lankton paper. It is local level set. In which, he divides the image into small region by Ball function. Then, the contour will separate these regions into inside and outside region. Each small regions have P_in and P_out. And we can calculate Bhattacharyya distance. I done that step. But I cannot implement final step as formual. Can you help me???
[image]
and Av and Au is area of inside and outside of these regions. This is my main code. You can download at [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/myu4teh245sw4u2/Lankton_Bha.zip)

```
  for its = 1:max_its   % Note: no automatic convergence test

%-- get the curve's narrow band
idx = find(phi <= 1.2 & phi >= -1.2)';  
[y x] = ind2sub(size(phi),idx);

%-- get windows for localized statistics
xneg = x-rad; xpos = x+rad;      %get subscripts for local regions
yneg = y-rad; ypos = y+rad;
xneg(xneg<1)=1; yneg(yneg<1)=1;  %check bounds
xpos(xpos>dimx)=dimx; ypos(ypos>dimy)=dimy;

%-- re-initialize u,v,Ain,Aout
Ain=zeros(size(idx)); Aout=zeros(size(idx)); 
B=zeros(size(idx));integral=zeros(size(idx));
%-- compute local stats
for i = 1:numel(idx)  % for every point in the narrow band
  img = I(yneg(i):ypos(i),xneg(i):xpos(i)); %sub image
  P = phi(yneg(i):ypos(i),xneg(i):xpos(i)); %sub phi

  upts = find(P<=0);            %local interior
  Ain(i) = length(upts)+eps;

  vpts = find(P>0);             %local exterior
  Aout(i) = length(vpts)+eps;

  %% Bha distance
  p = imhist(I(upts))/ Ain(i) + eps; % leave histograms unsmoothed
  q = imhist(I(vpts)) / Aout(i) + eps;
  B(i) = sum(sqrt(p.* q));
  term2= sqrt(p./q)/Aout(i) - sqrt(q./p)/Ain(i); %Problem in here===I don't know how to code the integral term 
  integral(i) =sum(term2(:));
end   

F =-B./2.*(1./Ain - 1./Aout) - integral./2;
```

Comment: why cant you inplement it?

Comment: Because it multiplies with a kernel (Gaussian kernel), I try to multiplies it by convolution, however, the result is not similar with paper result

Comment: OK. I see. Can you narrow the problem a bit? The feeling one has when opening this SO question is more or less: OMGOMG WHAT an equation, help, imouta here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this - no idea if its correct - its has no histogram smoothing (I dont think it is necessary)

```
if type==3  % Set up for bhatt

F=zeros(size(idx,1),2);

for i = 1:numel(idx)  

img2 = img(yneg(i):ypos(i),xneg(i):xpos(i)); 
P = phi(yneg(i):ypos(i),xneg(i):xpos(i)); 

upts = find(P<=0);            %local interior
Ain = length(upts)+eps;
[u,~] = hist(img2(upts),1:256);

vpts = find(P>0);             %local exterior
Aout = length(vpts)+eps;
 [v,~] = hist(img2(vpts),1:256); 

   Ap = Ain;
   Aq = Aout;
   In=Ap;
   Out=Aq;
    try
     p = ((u))  ./ Ap + eps;
     q = ((v)) ./ Aq + eps;
     catch
     g  
    end


 B = sum(sqrt(p .* q));

 F(i)=B.*((1/numel(In))-(1/numel(Out)))+(0.5.*(1/numel(In)*(q(img(idx(i))+1)...      /p(img(idx(i))+1))))-(0.5.*(1/numel(Out)*(p(img(idx(i))+1)/q(img(idx(i))+1))));
end
```

Comment: I didnt use one in this instance, as far as I can tell its just a smoothing parameter for the histogram differentiation. Id imagine that it could be approximated by just smoothing the image. Please note the maybes in this argument. There is also some code which I couldnt get access too here - http://cgm.technion.ac.il/Computer-Graphics-Multimedia/Undergraduate-Projects/2011/SegmentationRigidObjects/ProjectWeb/files/default.html. Maybe if you email they can provide you with the necessary pass. If you do get this magical formulation to work as written, it would be great if you could share it.

Comment: Yeah I tried to download it as well, when looking at James Malcolms implementation - he also doesnt use a kernel in his implementation. From experiment, it also looks like this distance measure is a terrible idea to use with localised region contours. It often gets stuck in regions where the mean does a better job. Especially when looking at the background and foreground pdf in homogenous regions close to the object of interest - I think this is one of those things where spending a lot of time on it well only educate us a little but get our work no where.

Comment: @user3546025: Right, James Malcomlms method is global active region based Bha distance. However, the paper that I shown is local active contour. So I think Lankton tried to improve it for inhomogeneity region. If you download the code from this website, Please share it to me via mjohn1282@gmail.com

Comment: Yeah I have made it for (well atleast tried to make it for) local region based active contours. If you downloaded Shawn Lanktons method just replace meth 1 or 2 with the code I added above and let it run. It works in some cases but when it doesnt I think its more a problem with the method than the script.

Comment: @user3546025: I download and modify Lankton code as your suggestion. However, It has some error. Please download my edit code version https://www.dropbox.com/sh/msi03g4r5qpsi7p/AABr7O6xj7Q1nrp6sDRSrPfza?dl=0 and let me know how to fix it. BTW, could you send to me the source code that you download from above link.

Comment: You are welcome to my code but I dont know how to message on here. Please message me and I will send you my code.